# Launch MacOS App from Terminal

Tags: macos, makefile, cmake

I wrote an application for MacOS that takes command-line parameters and hence needs to be run from `Terminal`. In `CMake`, I have these lines:

```
if(APPLE)
   add_executable(myApp MACOSX_BUNDLE myApp.cpp)
endif()

INSTALL(TARGETS myApp DESTINATION /usr/local/bin)
```

After `make install`, the app can be run from `Terminal` as:

```
/usr/local/bin/myApp.app/Contents/MacOS/myApp  <command-line-args>
```

The above is too cumbersome, due to `MACOSX_BUNDLE`, and I wanted to simply invoke it as `myApp`.

Comment: How much do you know about setting the PATH?

Comment: I did think of that, but isn't there a more elegant solution than manually setting path to the app contents folder? Is there a trick with `make install`?

Comment: There might be, but if it didn't fire for you then probably no. You're right and path is evil and lazy. I should be embarrassed. You can also place a symlink to your program somewhere that already is in the path.

Comment: set the $PATH variable to include the directory, the shell doesn't know where anything exists without it. if you echo $PATH you'll notice it points to all the directories where cli programs are executed

Comment: Dur. I'm being stupid. You control the program. You probably control the build script. Add the symlink-building instruction to the make install rules.

Comment: simply drop the `MACOSX_BUNDLE` and build it like a Linux/Win binary

Comment: @BradAllred Good suggestion, I actually do that for my other apps but this one I am forced to build it this way to make the application work. It has GUI keyboard callback functions.

Comment: You don't need to build an application as an `.app` bundle for it to have a GUI.

Comment: @duskwuff that is true, GUI works except keyboard callbacks don't. When I type a letter, the keyboard callback event is not triggered, letter appears on console instead. Sorry, going slightly off-topic, but long story short.

Comment: @dr_rk maybe you should open a question about why you seem to need to build as a bundle for the callbacks to work. I doubt you truly do.

Answer (score 0):

If you build a proper bundle with all necessary information in the `Info.plist`, you can open the App via `open -b $BundleIdentifier`. See [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH101-SW1) and the output of `man open` in your Terminal.